# Maximizing a Special Node-weight sum on a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)  $G=(V,E)$, also satisfying that if $(u,v),(v,w)\in E \implies (u,w)\in E$. For $S\subseteq V$, define the following set $\Gamma(S)=\left\{u \in S, \not\exists v\in S \mid(v,u)\in E\right\}$. This is, given a set $S$ find all the vertices that don't have an incident edge in the sub-graph induced by $S$. Let also $w_v$ be the weightfor each vertex $v$

I need to find a set of vertices $S^*$ maximizing $W(S)=\sum_{v\in \Gamma(S)}w_v$

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Thanks!